# sonarqube locally published but report is not generated via visual studio 2015 update 3

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I have installed sonarqube locally version : sonarqube-6.7.2
I am able to login in sonarbube locally using http://localhost:9000

created project and bind to one of my visual studio project.
But when I update in visual studio using sonarlint but not able to find anything on locally published site.
No report no issue even no code.

Using windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

SonarLint does not publish issues to SonarQube, you need to integrate [SonarScanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) into your CI build process to do that. You could do it as plain command line, as described in the documentation link above, or using the [plugin for Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/sonar) or the [VSTS/TFS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube).